# How to obtain the following angle relation?

Tags: trigonometry

I meet a trouble in solving the following trig-identity in my study:
[image: Figure]

If   $\delta+\phi=\theta$

> How to prove the following:   $$\tan{\delta}=\frac{\omega_l\sin{\theta}}{\omega_p+\omega_l \cos{\theta}}$$

---

I try to use $h=\omega_p\sin{\delta}$, where $h$ is the height of the triangle; however, I cannot find the next step.

Comment: Are these triangles right triangles?

Comment: @ErockBrox Not right triangles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quadrilateral in the picture is a parallelogram, therefore the opposite sides are equal.

By the [Law of sines](http://Law%20of%20sines)
$$\frac{\omega_p}{\omega_l}=\frac{\sin{\phi}}{\sin{\delta}}.$$
Hence, the requested relation holds iff
$$\frac{\sin{\delta}}{\cos{\delta}}=\tan{\delta}=\frac{\sin{\theta}}{\frac{\omega_p}{\omega_l}+ \cos{\theta}}=\frac{\sin{\theta}}{\frac{\sin{\phi}}{\sin{\delta}}+ \cos{\theta}}=\frac{\sin{\theta}\sin{\delta}}{\sin{\phi}+ \cos{\theta}\sin{\delta}}$$
that is
$$\sin{\phi}=\sin{\theta}\cos{\delta}-\cos{\theta}\sin{\delta}=\sin(\theta-\delta)$$
which holds because $\delta+\phi=\theta$.

Answer (score 2):

In a geometrical way instead, prolong the $\omega_p$ side, and from the diagonal end draw the height $h$ to it
[image]

then
$$
\tan \delta  = \frac{h}
{{\omega _{\,p}  + \omega _{\,l} \cos \theta }} = \frac{{\omega _{\,l} \sin \theta }}
{{\omega _{\,p}  + \omega _{\,l} \cos \theta }}
$$